# How to generate Zoho-oauthtoken for Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, oauth, zoho

I'm trying to send a Zoho Desk ticket reply from a Google Apps Script. We are stuck at generating the Zoho-oauth token mentioned in the Zoho API documentation.
[image]

First, we started by going here: https://api-console.zoho.com/

From the available options, we chosed client based app:
[image]

But on the next step, we don't understand how to fill in the fields:
[image]

Again, we are trying to use Zoho Api from a Google script (https://script.google.com/......) that will be run when we press a button in a Google Sheets file (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets.......).

How do we generate the auth token ? Community's help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: The process for getting the auth token is described in their Help Guide https://www.zoho.com/accounts/protocol/oauth.html

Comment: https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/ZohoCRM.gs

Answer (score 0):

You application (Your Apps Script code in this case) will need the credentials to receive a token from the Zoho API and be able to make requests to it.
When you click in the Sheets, it will execute the script, which will run in a Google server and delivered to your browser. In this case, the request to Zoho will be originated from a Google server. I would choose web-server credentials. But do go through the [OAuth Help Guide](https://www.zoho.com/accounts/protocol/oauth.html)